# How to disable Tomcat JARScanner

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

**How:** To disable Tomcat JARScanner?
**Why:** To stop Tomcat scan every .jar in my LIB folder.

According to [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html) it says that it is possible to disable it within context.xml. But it seems to not be working. (May be I am missing something)
I made an exhaustive search in forums and could not find the solution.

This is in context.xml (not working yet):

```
<JarScanner scanClassPath="false" scanAllFiles="false" scanAllDirectories="false"></JarScanner>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your attempted configuration. It's hard to guess why it's not working when you don't post what you've tried.

Comment: I've added the line i'am using in context.xml. Sorry and thanks

Comment: Do you want to disable scanning of all JAR files entirely? You have no `.tld` files that need to be auto-discovered and you don't use any annotations?

Comment: I removed the entry from web.xml and the issue stoped. Still wanting to disable JarScanner from Context.xml (for prototyiping purposes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add the JarScanner element as a child of the root Context element in the context.xml file.

I have this kind of META-INF/context.xml file in the war file for disabling the JarScanner:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <JarScanner scanClassPath="false" scanAllFiles="false" scanAllDirectories="false"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Is that the global context.xml file located at `/etc/tomcat8/context.xml`?   Can jar scanning be disabled on a web-app by web-app basis by instead placing the configuration in your web app's war file in `WEB-INF/web.xml`?

Comment: It can be disabled on web-app by bassis by using application META-INF/context.xml file

Answer (score 3):

you can disable the JarScanner globally for user-defined patterns by opening the file at

```
%TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/catalina.properties
```

and add a filename pattern to `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip` list.
For example, if you want to disable jar scanning completely you could add:

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=\
*.jar,\
```

NOTE: this may of course lead to issues if you're employing JSTL, as templates won't be found by the scanner

Answer (score 1):

in your java app add this :

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(final Context context) {
            ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for Spring Boot.

Basically, append a new ignored jar file to the existing list of jars to ignore. This way, you don't totally disable the scanner, affecting who knows what else.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                // db2 puts a ref to pdq.jar in the manifest, and tomcat then tries to find it, but it doesn't exist.
                // The jar isn't needed, so we just disable looking for it. You could also remove it from the manifest,
                // but that prob needs to be done after the build process.
                JarScanFilter jarScanFilter = context.getJarScanner().getJarScanFilter();
                if (jarScanFilter instanceof StandardJarScanFilter) {
                    StandardJarScanFilter filter = (StandardJarScanFilter) jarScanFilter;
                    String oldTldSkip = filter.getTldSkip();
                    String newTldSkip = oldTldSkip == null || oldTldSkip.trim().isEmpty() ? "pdq.jar" : oldTldSkip + ",pdq.jar";
                    filter.setTldSkip(newTldSkip);
                } else {
                    logger.warn("Unable to disable the tomcat jar scanner for pdq.jar. You may see a FileNotFound exception complaining of not finding a db2 pdq.jar file. You can probably ignore the error. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656596/how-to-disable-tomcat-jarscanner");
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```