# Tomcat JAR Scanner trying to scan apache-tomcat/lib/lib/ for JARs

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I'm upgrading to Apache Tomcat 8.5.15 from 6.0.44. When I start up the web server and deploy my web application, I get lots of warnings from `org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan` with the message

```
Failed to scan [file:/path/to/apache-tomcat/lib/lib/tomcat-jaspic-api-8.5.15.jar] from class loader hierarchy
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/apache-tomcat/lib/lib/tomcat-jaspic-api-8.5.15.jar (No such file or directory)
```

I don't understand why the scanner is looking inside `apache-tomcat/lib` for another directory named `lib`, which doesn't exist. My `CATALINA_HOME` is set to `/path/to/apache-tomcat` and the `common.loader` property in `catalina.properties` is set to the default:

```
common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"
```

I know that the warning can be safely ignored without affecting the web application, and that I can [turn off JAR scanning in `apache-tomcat/conf/context.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656596/disable-jarscanner-in-context-xml), but I'd still like to know the reason behind the `lib/lib` oddness.

Answer (score 1):

You have a library with a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF containing a relative Class-Path.

Look at each of the libraries being scanned, starting with the ones in Tomcat's lib/ directory, especially non-default ones you may have added. Check the MANIFEST.MF in each one for a Class-Path entry including one of your missing libraries, e.g. "lib/tomcat-jaspic-api-8.5.15.jar"

> lib/badlibs.jar

```
Class-Path: lib/notthere.jar lib/missing.jar
```

In my case an old locally developed library was in $CATALINA_BASE/lib with this class-path:

```
Class-Path: lib/servlet-api.jar lib/juli-6.0.26.jar lib/catalina.jar
```

Leading to the error:

```
StandardJarScanner.processURLs Failed to scan [file:${catalina.base}/lib/lib/juli-6.0.26.jar] from classloader hierarchy
```

Some code clean-up is in order.

Thanks to the [blog of Romain Manni-Bucau](https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/tomcat-failed-scan-lib.html) where I found my answer.